# Lucene Difference between OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND and deleteDocuments

Tags: lucene

I am pretty new to LUCENE search engine, want to know the functionality of OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND,  deleteDocuments? Also, indexSearcher.search method can accept either Term or Query as a parameter, to fetch documents. Can you help me out in which scenario I need to use term and query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `OpenMode` does not affect the behavior of `deleteDocuments`. It only affects what happens when you open the Indexwriter:

- `CREATE` - Creates a new index. If one already exists, it will be overwritten.
- `CREATE_OR_APPEND` - Uses an existing index, or creates it if none currently exists.
- `APPEND` - Uses an existing index. If none currently exists, throws an IOException.

I'm not aware of any `IndexSearcher.search` method that takes a `Term` as an argument. If you can link to what you are referring to, that might be helpful.

However, if you want to search for a term, you can just use [`TermQuery`](https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_6_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/TermQuery.html).

Comment: Thank You, Could you please explain to me what exactly Append method will do?